# python ide I made freezes when I use input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So I'm making a python IDE and am trying to use input() but it freezes when I try to run it and have input() in the code. Now I need some way to have it wait for input in the text box

IDE's code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from io import StringIO
import sys

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Logans python Ide")
window.geometry('400x200')
tout = None

# Text Widget
t = tk.Text(window, width=20, height=3)

t.grid(column=1, row=15)
def runner():
    global tout
    tmp = sys.stdout
    my_result = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = my_result
    my_in = StringIO(tout.get(1.0,"end-1c"))
    sys.stdin = my_in
    exec(t.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
    sys.stdout = tmp
    tout.insert(tk.END,my_result.getvalue())

btn = ttk.Button(window,text="run",command=runner).grid(column=0, row=15, padx=10, pady=25)
window.mainloop()
```

the code I try to use is:

```
print("enter you name")
name = input()
print("hi %s" % name)
```

I had it being a label at first but changed it to the text box to get input it still works normally but not when I use Input() I'm thinking of using

Comment: You need to open the select the console window and enter the input there.

Comment: You can accept user input in tkinter via a number of widgets, such as `Entry` or `Text`. Using `input()` in a tkinter app should be avoided - it's better suited for console-only applications.

Comment: ```tkinter.simpledialog.askstring()``` works but try to give help to make a terminal

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior.

When you use `input()` in a tkinter program, you will interrupt the event processing loop, causing the GUI to become unresponsive.
This is because `input()` does not return until the user presses the `enter` key. You could say it is kind of running its own event loop (but only for keystrokes).

If you want to collect information from the user in a GUI program, you could use a dialog box.

For example `tkinter.simpledialog.askstring()`; see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html).

Since you want to build a terminal-like interface for an IDE, I suggest you look at how `idle` (that comes with your Python installation) does that.

Comment: is there a fix for that

Comment: I am trying to make it an ide so is there a way i can use it with a the output text box like the terminal

Comment: See comment @JRiggles.

Comment: @LoganKocher Creating a terminal in a tkinter application is not an easy task even for an experienced developer.

Comment: @acw1668 Well said - I've only ever attempted to replicate console *output* in a tkinter app and that was a nuisance on its own

Comment: @JRiggles I thought that was pretty easy